# Unable to understand self-referencing many-to-many and filter in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to learn *Self-referencing many-to-many* and stuck on code segment

Let assume two models,Person and relation ship,as below:-

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    relationships = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Relationship',
                                           symmetrical=False,
                                           related_name='related_to')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING = 1
RELATIONSHIP_BLOCKED = 2
RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES = (
    (RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING, 'Following'),
    (RELATIONSHIP_BLOCKED, 'Blocked'),
)

class Relationship(models.Model):
    from_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='from_people')
    to_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='to_people')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES)
```

and person model contains following methods:-

```
def get_relationships(self, status):
    return self.relationships.filter(
        to_people__status=status,
        to_people__from_person=self)

def get_related_to(self, status):
    return self.related_to.filter(
        from_people__status=status,
        from_people__to_person=self)
```

I am unable to understand how these two methods are working and what they are returning.
I am unable to understand how filter and reverse-lookup are working together.

Please anyone help me to understand real intuition behind this.
Thanks in advance.
Hope to here from you soon.

Comment: The `to_people__from_person=self` and `from_people__to_person=self` are not necessary, these are already done through `self.relationships` and `self.related_to`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you explain how to_people__status=status, and from_people__status=status, working.